# Cómo incluir librerias python ya instaladas en ubuntu, dentro de un entorno virtual

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu

1. Monté Xubuntu en mi pc(es igual que ubuntu)
2. Instalé OpenCV (tardó como 2 horas instalando).
3. Instalé Anaconda que trae python 2.7 (pesa como 500mb y trae muchísimos paquetes, con el fin de evitar descargar paquetes adicionales)
4. Ahora quiero desarrollar con Django, pero necesito instalarlo.
5. Quiero instalar django DENTRO DE UN ENTORNO VIRTUAL.

Ya encontré que se pueden crear entornos virtuales con conda, pero siempre que intento crearlo me descarga python y dicho python no trae todos los paquetes que trae el instalador (500mb) que está disponible desde la pagina. Entonces si creo el entorno virtual así tendría que descargar manualemnte muchos paquetes y ovbio no es factible para mi :(

Lo que quiero es crear un entorno virtual que use el python de anaconda que ya descargué (500mb) e instalé. Esto debido a que ése python de anaconda está enlazado a librerías de opencv.

Concretamente tengo un proyecto en python con un framework llamado Flask (web) y al mismo tiempo usando librerías de opencv para reconocimiento de imagenes. Por tanto el python de anaconda que ya instalé hace todo lo que necesito. Pero quiero migrar ese proyecto de Flask a Django.

Comment: Si instalas anaconda usa conda para crear los entornos: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html.

Comment: Pero es que justamente, la idea de un entorno virtual es esa: tener una copia de python + librerías totalmente independiente de la del sistema.

Comment: Cuando uno descarga manualmente el instalador de anaconda, pesa 500mb y trae muchisimos paquetes (no necesito descargar paquetes por aparte)... Cuando creo el entorno virtual con conda (conda create -n mientorno1 python=2.7) solamente me descarga el python sin los paquetes adicionales y yo necesito más paquetes. Pero no los quiero instalar uno por uno, es muy molesto. (he editado la pregunta)... Gracias de antemano

Comment: Creo que puedes instalar todos los paquetes incluidos con anconda con `conda create -n mientorno1 python=2.7 anaconda`, esto es un poco fuerza bruta, lo normal es instalar solo los que necesites, puedes usar un archivo [spec](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/explicit-conda-environment-specifications/) o modificar el archivo de configuracion [.condarc](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html).